# generating WHERE IN () with groovy.sql

Tags: groovy

Is there a way to get Groovy's SQL library to generate a WHERE ... IN () that also protects against SQL injection?

I've tried the following (where stateList is a List or a String[] - I tried both):

```
WHERE p.state IN (${stateList})
```

The query was `WHERE p.state in (QLD, NSW)` - the strings are unquoted

```
WHERE p.state IN (${stateList.join(','})
```

The query was `WHERE p.state in (QLD, NSW)` - the strings are unquoted

```
WHERE p.state IN (${stateList})
```

The query was `WHERE p.state in ('QLD', 'NSW')` - the strings are quoted but I can inject SQL through stateList

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on how do you use this string, I assume that you're working with [Groovy SQL](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/sql/Sql.html)

In this case You should populate the query with '?' and use an additional parameter during the query execution.

The documentation contains an explicit paragraph about the SQL Injection (search for 'Avoiding SQL injection' at the link I've added at above as it doesn't provide anchor links)

So in this case it will be something like:

```
sql.firstRow("SELECT * from SOME_TABLE where state in '?','?'", [QLD, NSW])
```

This both avoids SQL injection because it uses `PreparedStatement` (as opposed to `Statement`) under the hood and also is better performance wise because the DB can avoid query parsing (query compilation) every time you call the DB.

Sometimes it might be more convenient to use named parameters (see section 4.5 [here](https://groovy-lang.org/databases.html)) but in a nutshell its the same technique under the hood I believe:

```
sql.execute "INSERT INTO Person (firstname, lastname) VALUES (:first, :last)", first: 'John', last: 'Smith'
```

Or:

```
sql.execute "INSERT INTO Person (firstname, lastname) VALUES (?.first, ?.last)", first: 'John', last: 'Smith'
```

Comment: And as a follow-up, I eventually got this to work but I had to use a List of ordinal parameters rather than a Map of named parameters - I'm using Groovy 2.4.15 and H2 1.4.196 and the named parameters kept coming through as NULL - maybe a bug in the database driver?

Comment: Well, it can be a lot of things, I haven't touched groovy for a long time, but basically probably its something with the syntax of what you do... Anyway, I think the best would be asking another question with the code snippets what how exactly does your code look like, feel free to add a link to the new question here so that I could get a notification and see it.